# Test python cli wheel package during local development

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-wheel, docopt

I'm developing a CLI tool in python using [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) and packaging via [wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/).

I can build and install the wheel package locally with the following:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
pip install dist/mypackage.whl
```

I can then test my package from the command line

```
mypackage --v
```

This works fine, but does not provided a very practical dev / test loop. In order to view any changes I need to uninstall the package, rebuild it and reinstall it.

Is there a more practical way to easily test and run changes locally during development?

Comment: While it is probably an overkill, you can try to use Docker

Comment: I don't see that docker is a solution here. I don't need to virtualize anything or run my package in a container. I need my code changes to be automatically compiled and available to test in the CLI (or similar)

Comment: I understand. What you probably need is something like `nodemon`, which can be used with python to some extend (or at least, this is what the documentation say). Since as far as I know there is not a python equivalent, my suggestion is to use Docker to build a clean environment to test your package

Comment: Thanks but I think this is still the wrong direction and unnecessary. What I need is the ability to install the python package but pointing to my source, such that when the package runs, it is my source code that gets interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Failing any better solution I have simply combined uninstall, build and install into a make task:

```
reload:
    pip uninstall -y mypkg && python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel && pip install dist/mypkg.whl
```

Now simply running `make reload` will achieve what I need.

Answer (score 1):

and by using
`pip install --editable .` in your dev folder?

You will have your package installed in editable mode, and continue to develop without having to reinstall all.